# Visual Studio 2012 .NET Framework 2.0 missing

Tags: .net, .net-2.0, visual-studio-2012

Very strange one.

I have a Windows 8 dev machine which has .NET 3.5 enabled in Windows features but after installing Visual Studio 2012 I can not see .NET Framework 2.0 in the New Project list. I can see 3.0 - 4.5 but nothing below it.  Problem is I need to support some specific .NET 2 apps.

I've tried:

1. Reinstalling Visual Studio completely.
2. Turning .net 3.5 support off and on in Windows features
3. Restarting several times during the above points
4. Checking using the Setup Verification tool mentioned here (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2008/10/13/8999004.aspx.  It returned that Framework 2.0 is installed and is valid.

I'm stumped.  Any ideas what be greatly appreciated.  Likewise, if anyone knows how to force install .NET 2 from the .NET 3.5 runtime SP1 installer I may give that a go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to work around this.  It seems to be an issue with running Visual Studio 2010 alongside 2012.  To fix I had to:

1. Uninstall both versions of Visual Studio
2. Turn off .NET 3.5 runtime
3. Install Visual Studio 2010
4. Turn on .NET 3.5 runtime
5. Install Visual Studio 2012

I did one of or more these initially but it only worked when I did in this specific order.